# I cannot download ms office files using JAX-RS, while code working fine for Pdf

Tags: excel, jax-rs

I am trying to make a request to make server response an excel file to the end user for download.But I am unable to show download dialogue box for excel or word, while I am able to use the same code for pdf and pdf files are downloading. what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/getDislikeData")
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Response getDislikeData() throws FileNotFoundException{
    ToExcel te= new ToExcel();
    te.createExcel();

    File file = new File("C:\\XLS\\offers.xls");
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("content-disposition","attachment;filename=offers.xls");
    return response.build();
}
```

The things I tried are @Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel") and @Produces(“application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet”).

I also tried @Produces("application/msword) and tried downloading word file instead of Excel but it also didnt helped.

It is only showing gibberish characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Actually it was not a coding issue but the browser issue. The browser was displaying the file on the screen instead of giving open/save prompt.